Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS unable to upgrade simply to 24.04 LTS
I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
and want to move to 24.04 LTS
however I am not being offered any prompts in the GUI.
I am a seasoned non techy user.
I think that I did get some prompts about upgrading a couple of weeks ago but when I look into this today I could not find a simple way to upgrade.

This may or not be related

I am having this update error

Unable to update "Snap Store":
(null): cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (snap-store), pids: 1843
Snap Store 41.3-77

I want to keep all my data!

You can look for upgrades by running the following from a terminal (basically the graphical updater with an extra flag man update-manger for details) : -
sudo update-manager -c


You cannot update the snap-store while it is running.
From a terminal do the following: -
sudo snap disable snap-store

Wait for it to stop
sudo snap refresh

Wait for all the updates
sudo snap enable snap-store


Thank you for your help
I ave now upgraded using the GUI

On reflection this was probably my problem
"Software Updater" is not responding. You may choose to wait a short while for it to continue or force the application to quit entirely.

After Waiting several times
and accepting a partial upgrade!
I am now using 24.04.1
